# Jquery change onclick function name

Tags: javascript, jquery

My question is! I am copying content from one table to another table and when I am doing this I need the function name to change to talentselect instead of driverselect which is attached to each table row. I still need to keep the variable values to parse. Just wondering if anyone can help me with this. I know that I should be binding the events to the elements with Jquery and not using OnClick but for now I need a solution to achieve this with the OnClicks.

Many Thanks!

The copying of the table

```
<table id="driverselectiontable" cellspacing="0">
<tr class="chosen" onclick="return driverselect(this, value, value);">
<td>driver</td></tr>
<tr class="odd" onclick="return driverselect(this, value, value);">
<td>driver</td></tr>
<tr class="even" onclick="return driverselect(this, value, value);">
<td>driver</td></tr>
<tr class="chosen" onclick="return driverselect(this, value, value);">
<td>driver</td></tr>
<tr class="even" onclick="return driverselect(this, value, value);">
<td>driver</td></tr>
</table>

<table id="talentselectiontable" cellspacing="0">
</table>


$("#talentselectiontable").html($("#driverselectiontable .chosen").clone(true).attr("class","odd"));
```

So basically I am copying all of the table rows that have the class named "chosen" but upon doing so I need to change the function call name to "talentselect". But each row in the table has different parameters being parsed which is allocated with PHP.

I have tried this piece of code but it is not working still

```
$("#talentselectiontable tr").attr("onclick").replace("driverselect", "talentselect");
```

Comment: You've posted not nearly enough information.  And yes, you need to get rid of that inline JavaScript.

Comment: if you already use `this` as param for your function, why you need change name?

Comment: As Sparky672 said, we need a little more information to help you. Specifically, it would help to see a little of the HTML making up the table row that holds the onclick attribute. The reason is, we need to know where the 'onclick' that needs changing is.

Comment: At what point do you want the function name changed? Am  I right in saying, that when somebody clicks the table row, the function driverselect() runs, and after it has run, change the name of the function in the table row, so next time it is clicked it does something else?

Comment: Get rid of those inline `onclick`'s and use jQuery to simply bind the new function to the new table rows.  A lot easier than dealing with this mess.  Again, putting more information in the question would be helpful... step-by-step what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see the actual HTML of your table, so this may be slightly incorrect, but should get you started.

```
$("#talentselectiontable tr").attr("onclick", "return talentselect(this, value, value);");
```

This whole problem would actually be a lot easier if you used event handlers rather than inline onclick attributes. You could then use the jQuery `live()` function (see http://api.jquery.com/live/) that would mean that JQuery would take care of changing the function for you. Your solution would look something like this:

```
$("#driverselectiontable tr").live('click', driverselect);
$("#talentselectiontable tr").live('click', talentselect);
```

And then whatever code to ensure that your cloning code gets called.

**Edit:** In response to the comment, it looks like this is what you're after:

```
var clickval = $("#talentselectiontable tr").attr("onclick");
$("#talentselectiontable tr").attr("onclick", clickval.replace('driverselect', 'talentselect'));
```

That should get you going.

With a view to better JavaScript practice however, I would recommend another approach entirely. Rather than storing your parameter values in the 'onclick' attribute, store them in a data attribute. So your HTML would look something like this:

```
<table id="driverselectiontable" cellspacing="0">
<tr class="chosen" data-myparam1="value" data-myparam2="value"><td>driver</td></tr>
```

And so on. You can then use JQuery to parse the values:

```
function driverselect() {
    var row = $(this),
        param1 = row.attr('data-myparam1'),
        param2 = row.attr('data-myparam2');

    // rest of the code goes here

}
```

Your markup will be cleaner, and you can use the `live()` jQuery functionality as described above.

Comment: hmmm yeah the only problem is that each rows parameter values are different, I tried this but it doesnt work. $("#talentselectiontable tr").attr("onclick").replace("driverselect", "talentselect");

Comment: FYI:  You should start getting used to the new way... [jQuery `.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Great thanks a lot for the info, yeah I was thinking about using the HTML5 data attribute but is it compatible with IE7, IE8? and what other alternatives are there? kind regards

Comment: There should be no problem using the HTML5 data attributes with IE7 or IE8 as browsers tend to just ignore anything they don't understand. Alternatives include storing the info in your class attribute or mucking around with the jQuery `.data()` function but personally, I would go with data atttributes as they're cleaner.